# How do I differentiate between an old browser and new browser for a style in CSS

Tags: css

The issue I'm having is that I don't know what they mean by a style rule that sets a font color to white for older browsers and white with 50% opacity in newer browsers and removes the underlining from the link text.. I didn't realize there was the potential to differentiate in the first place.

Update: How would I go about making it so that every time a mouse hovers over a text link, that it would display an image in place of a bullet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fallback styles. Write the universally understood property first, then the newer version of the property, which the modern browsers will use but the old browsers will simply ignore.

Example: set color to white for all browsers; then set color to white with 50% opacity for browsers that understand it.

```css
.yourclasshere {
  color: #FFFFFF; /* standard syntax understood by all browsers */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.5); /* new feature, ignored by old browsers */
}
```

Not sure how to handle the request to remove the underline in newer browsers. AFAIK all browsers always understood `text-decoration`. Maybe you could use `parent > child` for a selector.

Answer (score 1):

In that specific case you could use a fallback like:

```
.selector {
    color: #fff; /* white */
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* 50% opacity white */
}
```

So, as CSS rules are interpreted from top to bottom, modern browsers will set the color to transparent white. Old browsers won't be able to apply that rule since they don't support RGBA colors, so `#fff` will prevail.

Comment: you used js comments for css :( , only the first rule will be applied here

Comment: Thank you @GCyrillus for making me notice. I'm used to write SCSS which accepts the two slash notation. I'm sorry!